# Transitioning Blogger to new Google Apps

Tags: google-workspace, blogger, account-management

I just transitioned to the new Google Apps which let's you use additional services such as blogger with your Google Apps account.

I had a conflicting Google Account. [Google said](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181867) that when I attempt to login to a service which used that conflicting account, I would be presented with an interface that offers 3 choices: move my old data to a gmail account, move my data to a 3rd party account, or use a temporary gmail account.

When I attempted to login to my Blogger, it didn't present any of those options. It just let me create a brand new account as if I didn't have a Blogger at all. It's as if all my data is gone. I can no longer login using my old account.

How can I access my old blogger settings so that I can transfer it to my new account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, so the email tells you to log off and then log in to your Google Apps account. When you do this, you are currently **logged in as your Google Apps account** which shows up even when you go to Google pages such as http://google.com/accounts.

In order to be presented with this interface, you need to log out of your Google Apps account by pressing log off, then go to a page that let's you login to a Google account such as http://google.com/accounts. Next, login using your old credentials, which will **log you in to your old Google Account**, and present to you the transfer options.

When I tried using their interface, it took me to a page that says "The page you requested is invalid.", and had the "sign in" link on the top right. Pressing that showed a temporary address with the "%" in it. Attempting to login didn't work. I had to clear my cache and then login again.